# SVG only shown partially in Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg, rendering

I'm currently working with a Swiss map in SVG format. The `<svg>` tag is directly embedded inside a `<div>`.

In Chromium (Linux), everything just looks fine, but in Firefox (Linux) only a part of the SVG is shown. The SVG markup itself seems to be valid.

#### Chromium:

[image: SVG in Chromium]

#### Firefox:

[image: SVG in Chromium]

I created a jsfiddle with the source code for easier testing: http://jsfiddle.net/MKRXN/

Is this a Firefox issue, or is it some problem with the SVG? In any case, how can I get this to work correctly?

Comment: I'd guess you need to specify the image dimensions for Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set `height` and `width` to your parent `div` and then set the `svg` both height and width to `100%`:

HTML:

```
<div id="map" style="height: 500px;width:600px;">
```

SVG:

```
<svg
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.0"
   id="svg_main" style="height: 100%;width: 100%">
```

Check this code: http://jsfiddle.net/Kgs6J/

Comment: Nice, thanks! :) I tried setting the height/width of the container div before, but was missing the 100% setting for the svg element, that's why it didn't work for me at first.

Comment: @DaniloBargen Yes, this is because you should set `width` and `height` of the `svg` to `100%` in order to set the parent size to child element.

Comment: Alternately, you could give your SVG a useful intrinsic size, so that the browser doesn't default it to the CSS-defined replaced element default size.