# How to set the exact size of an inline SVG element?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, svg, d3.js

I am creating a visualization with d3.js:

http://bl.ocks.org/EE2dev/raw/cd904f10097b9921f1cc/

In that code I create an SVG element and set the size with this line:

```
var chart = d3.select("body")
  .append("div").attr("class", "chart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", outerWidth) // outerWidth = 960
  .attr("height", outerHeight) // outerHeight = 500
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "margin")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Testing the code in Chrome, everything works fine, the SVG has the desired size of (960, 500). When I open this site in Firefox, however, the SVG element is created with a different size, appearantly depending on the actual browser window size, e.g. (634, 856) in the case below.

[image]

How do I fix this behaviour to set the SVG to the desired fixed size for Firefox?

I tried several things, including wrapping a div around and/or following ideas I found elsewhere

- [SVG only shown partially in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136238/svg-only-shown-partially-in-firefox)
- http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/08/19/making-svgs-responsive-with-css/

But I didn't find a way to fix this problem for me that worked:(

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`outerWidth` and `outerHeight` are browsers Window properties. It is curious problem that these properties could be overwritten in Chrome but not in Firefox ([FF API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/outerWidth)). So when you set

```
outerWidth = 960;
```

then outerWidth is changed to 960 in Chrome. In the case of Firefox it is current window width and it can not be changed by the client script.
So rename `outerWidth` and `outerHeight` and it should be working.

```
svgWidth = 960;
svgHeight = 500;

...

.append("svg")
.attr("width", svgWidth)
.attr("height", svgHeight)
```

Comment: unfortunately, renaming the variable or even using the values (960, 500) directly does not change the behaviour in firefox.

Comment: I was wrong, you are right! The variables outerWidth and outerHeight get overwritten in Firefox. I didn't notice when I did the changes you suggested since I also used the names: innerWidth and innerHeight. There the same thing applies. Thanks so much !!