# image firefox chrome missmatch

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

i'm a first time poster, long time enthusiast.

So i'm working on my personal website, and i haven't got that much experience in html/css, but i've come across a strange mismatch between firefox and chrome. And i was wondering if the wise people of the internet could direct me to where my (probably obvious) error is.

The problem im experiencing is that firefox will cut of the last 2 letters of my image. Ive colored the different parts so its more visible. I'll also post my code for those who want to see that. If you guys could point me towards a solution i would be very much obliged.

Firefox:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5wA4.png
Chrome:
http://i.imgur.com/xumAiwk.png

```css
/* Reset
------------------------------------------------------------ */
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html { overflow-y: scroll;}
body { background:#ffffff; font-size: 13px; color: #666666; font-family: Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;}
ol, ul { list-style: none; margin: 0;}
ul li { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
h1 { margin-bottom: 10px; color: #111111;}
a, img { outline: none; border:none; color: #000; font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase;}
p { margin: 0 0 10px; line-height: 1.4em; font-size: 1.2em;}
img { display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;}
aside { font-style: italic; font-size: 0.9em;}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section { 
    display: block;
}

/* Structure */
#wrapper {
 width: 96%; 
 max-width: 920px;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 2%;
} 

/* Banner */
#banner {
 float: left;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color:red;
}

 #banner img {
  max-width: 450px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color:blue;
 }

#occp {
 float: left;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color:green;
}

 #occp img {
 max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color:yellow;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title> Demo | Responsive Web</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
  <link href="test.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/respond.min.js'></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
   <header>
    <div id="banner">
     <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15472320/logo.svg" alt="Banner" />
    </div>
    <div id="occp">
     <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15472320/occp.svg" alt="Electrical Engineering Student" />
    </div>
   </header>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like the issue is not the difference in how Chrome/Firefox handles CSS or HTML but how they handle SVG's. Loading just the SVG (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15472320/occp.svg) in each browser confirms this. To help any further we will need to look at your SVG's code. You should be able to open your SVG in any text editor and edit your post with it's code. Something in their is a little off, taking a shot in the dark it might be the viewbox.

Comment: Possible duplicate and the reason why this happens in firefox - (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830897/svg-renders-but-gets-cut-off-in-firefox-only-why) but the accepted answer does not contain a solution. Another duplicate question - (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136238/svg-only-shown-partially-in-firefox), the solution requires redundantly giving the SVG a height and width of 100%. These two sources combined should explain why it happens and how to fix it. Good luck mi amigo. If this doesn't work you may need to post your SVG's code for us to diagnose this.

Comment: I've made a jsfiddle with my SVG file: http://jsfiddle.net/51tL2bnm/ and now im trying to edit some values to make it work. So far i've tried to manually set the width a bit wider, but that gets me extra image width in chrome. Thanks for al the help so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the JS fiddle SVG file in the comments section I was able to set the width to 100% and get the graphic to be the same size in chrome and firefox, I have not tested opera, IE, Edge, or safari.

```
<svg
    ...
   width="100%"
    ...>
</svg>
```

JS Fiddle Fork of just the SVG

http://jsfiddle.net/7nn94k13/1/

Code Snippet with the SVG placed inside the original code

```css
/* Reset
------------------------------------------------------------ */
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html { overflow-y: scroll;}
body { background:#ffffff; font-size: 13px; color: #666666; font-family: Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;}
ol, ul { list-style: none; margin: 0;}
ul li { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
h1 { margin-bottom: 10px; color: #111111;}
a, img { outline: none; border:none; color: #000; font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase;}
p { margin: 0 0 10px; line-height: 1.4em; font-size: 1.2em;}
img { display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;}
aside { font-style: italic; font-size: 0.9em;}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section { 
    display: block;
}

/* Structure */
#wrapper {
 width: 96%; 
 max-width: 920px;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 2%;
} 

/* Banner */
#banner {
 float: left;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color:red;
}

 #banner img {
  max-width: 450px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color:blue;
 }

#occp {
 float: left;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color:green;
}

 #occp img {
 max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color:yellow;
 }
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title> Demo | Responsive Web</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
  <link href="test.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/respond.min.js'></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
   <header>
    <div id="banner">
     <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15472320/logo.svg" alt="Banner" />
    </div>
    <div id="occp">
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="100%"
   height="22.796349"
   id="svg3086"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.48.4 r9939"
   sodipodi:docname="New document 6">
  <defs
     id="defs3088" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.35"
     inkscape:cx="222.35964"
     inkscape:cy="-265.74468"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     fit-margin-top="0"
     fit-margin-left="0"
     fit-margin-right="0"
     fit-margin-bottom="0"
     inkscape:window-width="463"
     inkscape:window-height="423"
     inkscape:window-x="100"
     inkscape:window-y="100"
     inkscape:window-maximized="0" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata3091">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(-152.64036,-243.82116)">
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-size:31.58077812px;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;line-height:110.00000238%;letter-spacing:-4.82484102px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;font-family:Franklin Gothic Book;-inkscape-font-specification:Franklin Gothic Book"
       x="150.44296"
       y="261.72156"
       id="text4820-4"
       sodipodi:linespacing="110%"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         id="tspan4822-0"
         x="150.44296"
         y="261.72156"
         style="font-size:26.31731796px;letter-spacing:-0.87724388px">Electrical Engineering Student</tspan></text>
  </g>
</svg>
    </div>
   </header>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I could have sworn i tried that, but thanks! its working now :)

Answer (score 0):

I've made several changes to the HTML/CSS with no luck, as the commenter said it's most likely something to do with how FF handles SVG's.

If the `viewport` and `viewBox` do not have the same width to height ratio, the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute directs the browser how to display the image.

Here's two great resources to refer to on this topic.

http://jonibologna.com/svg-viewbox-and-viewport/
http://codepen.io/jonitrythall/blog/preserveaspectratio-in-svg

Alternatively, use a png or jpg, as these files aren't likely to have this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, ive been wrestling with the svg code but the viewbox and viewport doesnt seem to do what i want.